# Does anyone know how to fetch data from json in react native?

Tags: android, ios, json, react-native

I am new in react native and I need to take information from JSON file asynchronously on change text in input field.

```
 JSON:
  { "meta": {
     "code": 200,
    "api_version": "2.0.1.6.0",
    "issue_date": "20160620"
  },
  "result": {
    "total": 4,
    "items": [{
      "purpose_name": "Торгово-развлекательный комплекс",
      "name": "Asia Park, торгово-развлекательный комплекс",
      "full_name": "Алматы, Asia Park, торгово-развлекательный комплекс",
      "id": "9430047374983999",
      "building_name": "Asia Park, торгово-развлекательный комплекс",
      "address_name": "Райымбека проспект, 514а / Саина, 516",
      "type": "building"
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: try using AFNetworking for iOS. It automatically parse the JSON for you.

Comment: @BashirSidani, Questioner is talking about React-Native not ios Objective-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If it is a local JSON file you can just use `require`:**

```
const data = require('./data.json');
console.log( data.result.items[0].purpose_name );
```

**If it is a remote API request try `fetch`:**

```
fetch('https://example.com/data.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log( data.result.items[0].purpose_name ))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Answer (score 0):

If this file is local you may simply require it, it will get parsed automatically. If it is on some server you need to use the [Fetch API](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.27/docs/network.html#fetch).